# Time limit on the execution of a mathematical model

Tags: python-3.x, optimization, mathematical-optimization, gurobi, time-limiting

[image: 1]

I have a mathematical model that takes a long time before returning the solution.

Is it possible to insert a parameter that blocks the execution of the model after a certain time? I would like it to give me a result even if it is not excellent.
I'm programming with Python and to optimize I use Gurobi.

Thank you!

Comment: There are several ways to answer this. Please post a sample log showing the output.

Comment: I've added above an example of how I would like the solution after the model has run for some time. I would like to choose the duration of the execution.